# Is there a way provide basic authentication to an ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I want to create a self-hosted ASP.NET Core application that authenticates a single user for access and allows the user to change their password.  Once authenticated, the user can access the application content.  This mechanism is quite similar to how you would login to your home router... when you open a browser to the router IP, you are taken to the login screen.  Once authenticated, you can change router settings and change the administrative password.

There is no need for:

- New user registration
- Two factor authentication
- Forgotten password recovery
- Personal data management
- Email verification
- Etc...

I have a proof-of-concept working using ASP.NET Core Identity, but the default UIs provide way too much functionality.  I understand you can disable/customize the default UIs via scaffolding which works, but creates a ton of project clutter.

Is there an alternative I should consider?  Or am I stuck with all the scaffolding boilerplate code?

Comment: Scaffolding and removing functionality is the way to go. Identity provides an incredible, well-tested, well-made platform that saves you tons of hours of development. Consider the amount of time you would need to create just the part of the Identity framework that you need. Compare that to scaffolding and deleting functionality you don't want to support. I bet you that the latter will inevitably save you a lot of time.

Comment: I agree, just scaffold everything of Identity and remove what you don't need. That's the easiest way and you know it works - it's part of the framework. If in the future you want to add some features - it won't take much time at all

Comment: [Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) has fallen out of favor, but there are middleware packages available like [Bazinga.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic](https://github.com/bruno-garcia/Bazinga.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic) and [idunno.Authentication.Basic](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication/tree/master/src/idunno.Authentication.Basic) that fill the gap.